# Formal "The Client has no claims as to the quality of works" in german

Tags: formality

When drawing up documents it is also necessary sometimes to state that

> The Client has no claims as to the quality of works.

My possible translation for it is

> Der Kunde hat keine Ansprüche für die Qualität der Arbeit.

Is there also a more formal way to say the same?

Comment: Just out of curiosity... You posted a lot of these questions, looking for formal terms for a very specific kind of protocol that is, and it seems to me that you're not proficient in German. So, what are the reasons you (need to) do this?

Comment: @Em1 as I was mentioning before in older posts, I do not live in german- or english-speaking country. I live in Russia and I am a programmer who deals with legal documents. So the formality is of the highest priority here. And no, I'm not proficient in both these languages. But I'm intended to master them.

Comment: @Em1 In post soviet countries these phrases are common for majority of documents. So, thus I can help a lot of people to find a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly.

You cannot use "Ersatzanspruch" for "claim" in general (that would be only "Anspruch"). "Ersatzanspruch" means the "right to replacement", and you can only use it when dealing with replacing defect items.

The preposition with "Anspruch haben" is "bezüglich" (with genitive) or "an" (with accusative): "Anpruch bezüglich der Qualität" oder "Anspruch an die Qualität".

I am not a lawyer, but German law tends to be quite consumer friendly, and overly broad clauses like that will be considered invalid and hence void if the case goes to court. In a b2b setting, I doubt that any sane customer would sign a clause that denies him a minimum quality standard.

German law also allows the seller to fix a broken product instead of replacing it when a customer complains (Nachbesserung). If that is your intention (given you used Ersatz (replacement)), you're already covered by default.

If this is text for a contract or legally binding agreement, by all means get a lawyer.

Comment: By the way, I forgot to mention. I live in Russia. In post soviet countries there's a document called "PROTOCOL OF DELIVERY-ACCEPTANCE OF RENDERED SERVICES". I guess it is "Projektabschlußbericht" in german language. In such a document a clause about quality has to be present.

Comment: I know the type of document you are (probably) referring to as `Abnahmeprotokoll`. When reading "Projektabschlußbericht" I would rather think of a contractor-internal and rather informal, in particular not legally binding document.

Comment: @Matthias Wow, rather good suggestion! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Robert. Clauses like this could be formulated differently depending on context, and that's where you'll want to be very sure of what exactly it is you're putting in your contract.

Just to add another possible meaning to the list, there is also "Ansprüche geltend machen". It already has the term "gelten" - "to be valid" - in it. In English terms, I think "to state a claim to sth." comes closest.

> Der Kunde kann keine Ansprüche bezüglich der Qualität geltend machen.

German doesn't really have a "formal" form, such as Japanese for example, but instead several levels of dispassion ;-) However, there is one thing to make everything sound more formal in German: you can leave out the Subject and make a passive sentence.

> Ansprüche seitens des Kunden bezüglich der Qualität können nicht geltend gemacht werden.

This is not proper to put into any legal document, but if you want something to simply sound very formal and important (and also somewhat bloated), you could do that where it's possible.